# Is it possible to control gui tools that do not have cli support with cli?

Tags: bash, command-line, gui

How can we manage a program that can only be used from a graphical interface through the bash shell. I'm not just saying to running the program. I mean being able to use the functions of the program from the command line. Is there a method where I can keep track of which commands the graphical interface is executing in the background? Or any alternative method that I can use the graphical interface via cli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in general. You can see what syscalls is the program using with `strace` but not the "commands" it is using.

If you only need to control a running GUI program from CLI, you can try `xdotool` to "press" keys and move/click with the mouse. It would be hard to really control the program, but if you need something simple, it could do the trick.

Other option would be to use [Dogtail](https://gitlab.com/dogtail). It's a tool for testing GUI and uses accessibility interfaces to control the application. You can write a simple Python script to control the app and it should also work with the "fake" Xvfb X server.